# Kendo DataSourceRequest and DataSourceResult inside console app

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I would like to use Kendo's `DataSourceRequest` to save the filters applied to a grid. I would then like to use those filters from inside a separate non web app to construct a `DataSourceResult`.

The problem is that I would need to include `Kendo.MVC` but I do not want to take a dependency on `System.Web` or any MVC components.

I am currently considering constructing the Queryable and then saving the query to be run later instead of creating the data source result myself but it does not seem like a good way to go.

I was also considering saving the expression tree that generates the query and serializing it but did not find a reliable way of doing this.

I was wondering if anyone else had any recommendations for how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to just go with using the extension methods `.Where`, `.Sort` and `.Group` to generate an `IQueryable` to save the SQL query. The query can later be run inside another app.